# Javascript syntax for using a varable within a section reference

Tags: javascript, livecycle-designer

I have a form with the structure:
Form1

- parentSection1

  - childSection1
  - childSection2
  - childSection3... etc

I have made an array of all the childSection names (currentParent[]) and need to use it in a variable that accesses the nodes of each childSection.

```
var childNode = Form1.parentSection1.childSection1.nodes;  // this works if I reference it directly
```

what I need to work but can't get the syntax correct is:

```
var childNode = Form1.parentSection1.currentParent[i].nodes; // where i loops within a larger function
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean `var childNode = Form1.parentSection1[currentParent[i]].nodes;`

Comment: What is the type for `parentSection`, and what loop are you using? if it's a `NodeList` - which is not a traditional array - you may want to revisit how you loop over it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: ``var childNode = Form1.parentSection1[`currentParent${i}`].nodes;``